# RDP Shared Printer works fine, but not when the IIS application tries to print to it

Tags: c#, .net, iis, rdp

I have no issues printing a Windows test page to the printer over RDP, but the application running from IIS cannot print to the shared RDP printer. After setting the PrinterSetting accordingly, which works outside of RDP, it sees the printer as invalid and offline.

I've seen some advice on setting the permission on the printer for the user running the IIS application, but all the security settings are disabled over RDP for the redirected printers being shared over RDP.

Both of the conditions below are returning false over RDP to the shared pritner. I have tried just printing anyway, and as expected, I got an exception since it's not able to access the printer.

```
if (!printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid || !IsPrinterOnline())
```

```
private bool IsPrinterOnline()
{
    bool printerIsOnline = false;
    string printerName = _printerName;
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '{0}'", printerName);
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcherPrinters = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcherPrinters.Get())
    {
        printerIsOnline = !printer["WorkOffline"].ToString().Equals("True");
    }

    return printerIsOnline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect to a machine over RDP, and you bring your printers with you, that allows the applications running *on your profile* to access your remotely attached printer.

However, IIS applications run in a different user context, so they won't be able to access any printers which are available on your user session. Typically they can only access printers which are available systemwide. Even if IIS is configured to run the application pool and the site as the same user who is remotely connected, I don't think IIS will be able to print to the printer because it's a different instance of the users's profile.

The best way would be to connect to the remote printer directly over UNC, instead of trying to print to it over the RDP connection.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will give that a try and mark this answer accordingly afterwards.

Comment: Your suggestion proved useful. I did run into an issue when trying to connect to the printer still from within the Hyper-V. Ultimately, what worked really easily was exploring the path \\hostPCNameOrIP, and assuming the Network Printer shows up, right click on it and click Connect.

The pain in adding this printer was trying to use the wizards in Settings > Printers & Devices. Nothing seemed to work here.